# How to get the size of a View?

Tags: android, bitmap, view

So I'm trying to make my android app build a bitmap to the size of an imageview. The imageview's size changes based on the size of the screen, so how could I pass the size to a method that makes a bitmap that is always the size of the imageview?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass your imageview object to your method which creates bitmap. Use that object to get height and width.